# Firing Actions from combobox.selectedvalue with c# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my dictionary with strings and actions defined

```
SortedDictionary<string, Action> buttonoptions = new SortedDictionary<string, Action>
{
      {"Left Click", DoMouseClick()},
      {"Right Click", DoRightMouseClick()},
      {"Windows Key", wKey()}
};

abuttonCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(buttonoptions, null);
abuttonCombo.DisplayMember = "Key";
abuttonCombo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And here is where i want to run the relevant action:

```
if (stateOld.Gamepad.Buttons != GamepadButtonFlags.A && stateNew.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.A)
{
    //run the relevant action from the comboBox.SelectedValue
}
```

How would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you create `Action` within the `SortedDictionary` with `new Action`.

```
    SortedDictionary<string, Action> buttonoptions = new SortedDictionary<string, Action>
    {
          {"Left Click", new Action(DoMouseClick)},
          {"Right Click", new Action(DoRightMouseClick)},
          {"Windows Key",new Action(wKey)}
    };
    comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(buttonoptions, null);
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Create the methods DoMouseClick, DoRightMouseClick and wKey, each returning void.

```
private void wKey()
{
}

private void DoRightMouseClick()
{
}

private void DoMouseClick()
{
}
```

Finally, you can use dynamic to get the `Action` and run it. Make sure you use `SelectedItem` and not `SelectedValue`.

```
    dynamic selection = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    var selectionMethod = selection.Value;
    selectionMethod();
```